# Error locating server/instance specified | Visual Studio

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio

I am working on an assignment and have been stumped by this error for 2 days now. For some reason when I am adding a product through my program, it cannot connect or reach the database that is used, which is `Books.mdf`

The connection method I got from the book, which I had to make a separate class for just the connection.

```
class Connection
{
    public static SqlConnection GetConnection()
    {
        string connectionString = @"Data Source=localhost\\SqlExpress;" +
                      "Initial Catalog=Books;Integrated Security=True";

        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        return connection;
    }
}
```

And here is my add method where I get this error

> A network-related or instance specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or not accessible.

Code:

```
public static void addProduct()
{
    SqlConnection connection = Connection.GetConnection();

    string insert = @"INSERT INTO Products (ProductCode, Description, UnitPrice) " + 
                     "VALUES (@ProductCode, @Description, @UnitPrice)";

    SqlCommand insertCommand = new SqlCommand(insert, connection);
    insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductCode", product.Code);
    insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Description", product.Description);
    insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UnitPrice", product.Price);

    try
    {
        connection.Open();
        int productCount = insertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    catch (SqlException ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        connection.Close();
    }
}
```

The `.mdf` file is located locally in the project. At first it showed me that it wasn't compatible so I had to upgrade it, but still running into the same error.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have Sql Server Management Studio? If not you can also use the Sql Server Object Explorer in VS. See if you can connect to the database directly with either of these tools.

Comment: @Tim if you mean Test Connection when I click "Modify" in Server Explorer, I get "Test Connection Succeeded". This file was given to me as apart of the assignment, I was just supposed to add the code.

Comment: `Server Explorer` or `Sql Server Object Explorer`? These are 2 different windows (look under `View` to find others). But strangely I don't have "Modify" as an option on either...

Comment: Yes I see what you are talking about. i got Sql Server Object Explorer. When I right click on it, I get the "Disconnect" option, so it is showing it is connected...

Comment: In that same dropdown, look at `Properties` and double-check the connection string

Comment: If it doesn't match, try replacing the one in your code with this one.

Comment: The connection string is an exact copy from the slideshow/book. I tried replacing it with the connection string under properties and got the same error. EDIT - Actually, it said it was unable to login. Hmm..

Comment: Did you try @paparazzo's answer?

Comment: Yes I did, no success. I get an error after changing the connection string to the one under properties that says it was able to connect to the server but there was an error during login, pipline or end of pipe(?)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `@` or one of the `\`.  You are currently getting `\\`.